# Cassandra performance issue with Akka cluster sharding

Tags: performance, scala, cassandra, akka, sharding

**My application:**

- akka cluster 2.5.x;
- akka sharding with evenly distributed function;
- cassandra plugin "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-cassandra"(default configuration);
- dedicated single-node Cassandra 3.3;

My app simulates kind of financial app that acts on an account supporting the following operations: create account, debit/credit. If an entity actor gets such requests it will persist an event and return back the ack response to a client. 
It created 2 types of tests: one is with in-memory and other is with Cassandra plugins.
In-memory plugin - the app kept up till 20k requests per seconds.
Cassandra plugin - only 4k requests per seconds and we got the exception: Cassandra driver exception: pool is busy.
Let me ask my question what bottlenecks I met with Cassandra?
Thanks.